# Modifying StreamReader To Give Error Messages If File Not Found

Tags: c#

Help! I'm very new to C# and code just occasionally, so please be gentle.

I'm trying to create a "kinder" method of opening a text file for reading - one that will give the user a bit more friendly information if the file cannot be located when it is attempted to being opened. 
To do this I'm creating my own "TextFileStreamReader" class. This is essentially the same as StreamReader but gives some error messages if the file cannot be found. If the file is successfully found, I'm wanting return an instance StreamReader. But I don't think I'm allowed to do this.

Any hints as to how I should go about achieving what I would like to do?

```
//Trying to create a gentler class to a text file for reading
public class TextFileStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    public static TextFileStreamReader(string fullfilename) : base(string)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullfilename);
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} successfully opened.", fullfilename);
            return reader;  //Can't do this - but how do I return a StreamReader?
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
            "Can not find file {0}.", fullfilename);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
            "Invalid directory in the file path.");
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
            "Can not open the file {0}", fullfilename);
        }
    }
}
```

Desired usage

```
TextFileStreamReader myreader = New TextFileStreamReader("C:\Test\TestFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following class to create a stream for a given file path that will allow you to have your desired usage, which is to create the stream with a single line of calling code:

```
public class TextFileStreamReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of the StreamReaer class for a given file path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The complete file path to be read.</param>
    /// <returns>A new instance of the StreamReader class if the file was successfully read, otherwise null.</returns>
    public static StreamReader CreateStream(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(path);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "File {0} successfully opened.",
                path);

            return reader;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                "Can not find file {0}.",
                path);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                "Invalid directory in the file path.");
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                "Can not open the file {0}",
                path);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The usage of this would then be:

```
StreamReader streamReader = TextFileStreamReader.CreateStream(@"C:\Test\TestFile.txt");
// ...
```

You would obviously need to check if the streamReader variable is null before using it but this should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Allan! That does exactly what I want. I was surpised to see that you didn't have to instantiate an instance of your TextFileStreamReader class but could refer to it directly with StreamReader streamReader = TextFileStreamReader.CreateStream(@"C:\Test\TestFile.txt");

Comment: No worries HedgePig.  The reason that the CreateStream() method can be called without instantiating an instance of of TextFileStreamReader class is because the method is marked as static, meaning it doesn't require an instance of the class to be called.

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Ha! Your explanation is _very_ helpful, as is the link. Suddenly a whole lot of things fall into place!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public class TextFileStreamReader
{
    private string _FullFileName;

    public TextFileStreamReader(string fullfilename)
    {
        _FullFileName = fullfilename;
    }

    public StreamReader GetStream()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_FullFileName);
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} successfully opened.", _FullFileName);
            return reader;  //Can't do this - but how do I return a StreamReader?
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
            "Can not find file {0}.", _FullFileName);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
            "Invalid directory in the file path.");
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
            "Can not open the file {0}", _FullFileName);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

and call the class like this:

```
TextFileStreamReader tfsr = new TextFileStreamReader("fullfilename");
StreamReader sr = tfsr.GetStream();
//...
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, Wudge. That's definitely an improvement (because it actually works!) but I'm hoping to be able to do everything with a single line. It seems theer must be a way to do this but I can't think how.